# Send html form data to two separate tables in the database using sql and php

Tags: php, sql, prepared-statement

I have these 2 tables:

```
ornaments (ornament_id, ornament_name)
ornament_to_size (ornament_id, size_id, ornament_type, colour, material, finish, height, width, weight, location, price, description, image_path)
```

And I want to create a form in admin to insert a new ornament item into the database. What would be the best way of doing this? I need to insert in both tables which is making it more difficult for me. The ornament_id in the ornaments table is obviously the PK and the PK in the ornament_to_size table is ornament_id and size_id as a composite key.

The reason there is an ornament to size table is because an ornament can have more than one size like so:

```
ornament_id = 3 & size_id = 1
ornament_id = 3 & size_id = 2 
ornament_id = 3 & size_id = 3
```

I just want to know what the method would be not the actual code

Comment: There are ways to dynamically add inputs to a form so that you can enter in multiple ornament_to_size rows with a single submission of the form. (Or if you knew that you will only ever want to submit 3 ornament_to_size rows then you can just put 3 static sets of inputs for the ornament_to_size rows.) Now I have to ask: Is size_id truly an id? Meaning it is the id to another table (perhaps named size)?

Comment: Oh sorry, I 4got to say that I have a sizes table with the names of each size corresponding to the size id. Also, each ornament can have different sizes that have different dimension measurements. So one ornament can be classed as 'small' and so can another ornament - but they may both have different dimensions

Comment: Okay, but the approach will basically be the same as what I described before: You will collect the information for the new ornament as well as the different associated sizes in the same form (possibly with inputs that can be dynamically added for more sizes). On the server side you will gather the information for the ornament and insert that first so that you can get the ornament_id for the ornament just inserted (perhaps with [`lastInsertId`](http://pt2.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php)) which you will need to insert the ornament size rows. Does this answer the question?

Answer (score 1):

if the size table has already got the value in it you have two choice to let the user insert the data:

- select if you want to let the user add a single new value
- checkboxes field if you want the user to insert more then one,
  remember   to name it as 'checkboxname[]'  so that php can use it as
  an array.

In both cases use the id of the size as value.
On the Db inserting part you will have to parse the form data, then perform:

- a Insert into the ornament table, straight after perform a
  LastInsertId() query (this is pdo function but you can make it in mysql
  too) on it and save the result in a var.
- perform a subsequent query into the ornament_to_size table, using
  the var you have saved as ornament_id value.

Remember that if you have chose to use checkboxes you can just run a foreach with the $_POST['checkboxname[]'] to insert all the new rows thanks to how PhP read the POST .

Comment: Thanks for your help mate. I kinda get it. I will have to look into it.